# Search multiple collections in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I have two collections, Movies and Shows.

```
const ShowsSchema = new Schema({
title: {
 type: String,
 required: true
       },
description: {
 type: String,
 required: true
},
image: {
 type: String,
 required: true
})
```

Currently I'm only able to search data from one collection but I want to fetch data from both. After looking through some solutions on the website I came across the $lookup field.

```
 router.get('/:query', (req, res, next) => {
  const query = req.params.query;
  Show.aggregate([{

   $lookup: {
    from: "Movies",
    localField: "title",
    foreignField: "title",
    as: "movies"
     }
  }], () => {

  Show.find({
  title: {
    $regex: new RegExp(query),
    $options: "$i"
  },

}, (err, shows) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  res.json(shows);
  });
 });
});
```

I'm stuck here any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: update question with Movies schema!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.get('/:query', (req, res, next) => {
   const query = req.params.query;
   Show.aggregate([{
       $match : {
        title: {
            $regex: new RegExp(query),
            $options: "$i"
        }
      }
   },{
      $lookup: {
         from: "Movies",
         localField: "title",
         foreignField: "title",
         as: "movies"
      }
   }],(err, shows) => {
     if (err) {
         console.error(err);
     }
     res.json(shows);
   });
 });
```

Hope this is helpfull.!